# Multiple Background Subregions in Mathematica Grid

Tags: background, grid, wolfram-mathematica

I can`t figure out how to define several subregions with different color background as in the below.

Any Idea ?

Many thanks,

LA

```
Grid[Table["g", {4}, {7}],
Background -> {None, None, {{{1, 3}, {1, 3}} -> LightRed}}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply list the regions and colors as you already have the first one:

```
Grid[Table["g", {4}, {7}], 
 Background -> {None, None, {
    {{1, 3}, {1, 3}} -> LightRed,
    {{3, 4}, {4, 7}} -> LightBlue
  } } ]
```

[image]

Comment: @500, you're welcome, and welcome to StackOverflow.  Please consider voting for and accepting good answers.  [See this FAQ entry.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: Sure ! As soon as I`ll have my 15 "Reputations" !

Comment: @500 thank you. :)  Don't be too quick to accept an answer, as it may cause others who could give an even better answer to skip over your question because it is resolved.  Also, you can change which answer is accepted at any time, and if someone posts a better solution, go ahead and accept that.

Answer (score 7):

Just as a side note, a usual requirement is to specify background colors depending on values.

For that you can do:

```
k = Table[RandomInteger[{1, 2}], {4}, {7}];
Grid[k,
 Background ->
  {None, None,
   Join[
    Position[k, 1] /. {x_, y_} -> ({x, y} -> LightRed), 
    Position[k, 2] /. {x_, y_} -> ({x, y} -> LightBlue)]
   }]
```

[image]

**Edit**

If you don't know *a priori* the range of values, you may try something like:

```
k = Table[RandomInteger[{1, 20}], {4}, {7}];
Grid[k,
 Frame -> All,
 ItemStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 16], 
 Background ->
  {None, None, 
   Flatten@Array[List[##] ->
                   ColorData["Rainbow"][(k[[##]] - Min@k) / Max@k] &, 
           Dimensions@k]
  }  
]
```

[image]